# Loading data using multiple navigation properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I have the following Entities:

```
public class BetSelection
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int BetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Bet Bet { get; set; }
        public long SelectionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Selection Selection { get; set; 
    }
public class Selection
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int SelectionTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual SelectionType SelectionType { get; set; }
    }

public class SelectionType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I am using the following query to get the required BetSelection model:

```
public async Task<BetSelection> GetAsync(int tableId, int roundId, string SelectionTypeName)
        {
            return await GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(bs => bs.Selection.GameTableId == tableId && bs.Selection.RoundId == rounded && bs.Selection.SelectionType.Name == SelectionTypeName,
includeProperties: $"{nameof(BetSelection.Selection)},{nameof(BetSelection.Selection.SelectionType)}");
        }

public async Task<T> GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            if (includeProperties != null)
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);

            return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

but it is throwing the error:

```
"Invalid include path: 'SelectionType' - couldn't find navigation for: 'SelectionType'_   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

looks like the navigation properties are used in the wrong way. Am I missing something?

Comment: `nameof(BetSelection.Selection)` gives you "Selection" not `BetSelection.Selection` so to work with `NavigationPropertyPath` prefix your properties with the entity type i.e, `BetSelection.Selection`.

Comment: @HMZ It works fine with BetSelection.Selection using nameof(). the problem is with BEtSelection.Selection.SelectionType

Comment: Did you check the output of `nameof(BetSelection.Selection.SelectionType)`?

Comment: @HMZ That is my question.it is throwing an exception. I am looking for an answer to how to include that property.